# specifying Staging and Production Deployment URLs for MVC WebRole

Tags: azure

I have a question on setting site URLs for staging and production deployments for an MVC 4 webrole project.

Lets say the cloudservice name was `helloworld`. When I create a staging deployment for the `helloworld` service, I need the URL to be something like `staging.helloworld.cloudapp.net`, and production/deployment to be `helloworld.cloudapp.net`

Is this possible? I didn't find any way in the cscfg file.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, it's not possible for you to specify a domain name for staging environment. This has been one of the most requested feature: http://www.mygreatwindowsazureidea.com/forums/169386-cloud-services-web-and-worker-role-/suggestions/1282603-pick-a-dns-name-for-staging.

As mentioned in the comments in the link and what I have seen in some of the threads on various community forums, a general recommendation would be to have **`a separate cloud service as your staging environment`**. You could then deploy your application in the production slot of that cloud service and get a DNS name for that.